# My MVC4 website not work on IIS 10 on windows 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-10

Previously I had a MVC4 website without any problems hosted on windows 8.1 but now after migrate to windows 10 I see many problems like:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
required to service this request. Please review the following specific
parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ClientSide.MvcApplication'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
Inherits="ClientSide.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
ASP.NET Version:4.6.79.0
```

Comment: did you build the project?

Comment: Yes I build several times and clean solution

Comment: Check the `bin` folder just to ensure that you have `ClientSide.dll` if you do, try enabling Fusion logs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to see what is happening during the assembly load. This is possibly a permissions issue...

Comment: Guys I'm really sorry for this, I do a terrible mistake. I don't see the Configurations Manager and my project build was skipped!!!
So now I have compiled dll and the problem fixed